# Writing Dictionary Of Lists To Excel Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, error-handling, openpyxl

I'm trying to output my dictionary of data to excel, but receiving an iterable error.

The dictionary looks like:

```
d = {123: [1, 3, 7], 144: [5, 8, 10]}

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
wb.get_sheet_names() 
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title = 'Data Output' 
next_row=1
for key, values in won_bids:
     sheet.cell(column=1, row=next_row, value=key)
     sheet.cell(column=2, row=next_row, value=values)
     next_row += 1

Workbook.close()
```

Getting "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" error.

Comment: What exactly is the value of  `won_bids`? It is probably an `int`, hence the error.

Comment: This isn't the cause of your error, but the last line of your code should be `wb.close()` not `Workbook.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `d` and `won_bids` are actually the same thing, you should probably just call the `.items()` method to get the tuple of key and value.